# How to calculate the number of objects I get from the loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I filtered my set of users(array) with if(elem.id_verified). I now get 77 users objecta. I just want to take the number of these objects. I tried with console.log(this.numOfunverifiedUsers.length) but i get 77 underfined. My question is how to assemble all objects and get that number. Maybe my logic is going in the wrong direction.

```js
this.users=response.data.users

this.numOfunverifiedUsers = []

this.users.forEach(elem => {
  if (elem.id_verified === 0) {
    this.numOfunverifiedUsers = elem
    console.log(this.numOfunverifiedUsers.length)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.numOfunverifiedUsers.push(elem)
```

Push the element in array.
`this.numOfunverifiedUsers = elem` , replace it with above

Comment: Yes thank you. I now get number with this.numOfunverifiedUsers.length and share in html :)

Comment: The point is that by not using `.push()` but `this.numOfunverifiedUsers = elem`,  you overwite the array with the element object instead of placing it inside the array you declared. So after the loop finishes, `numOfunverifiedUsers` equals the last element that passed the `id_verified` test instead of an array containing all those elements. And for the record, like the other answers mention, you're basically using forEach() as filter() .

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
console.log(this.users.filter(function (val) {
    return val.id_verified === 0
}).length)
```

filter items that are `id_verified === 0` and count their length.

Answer (score 0):

I think would be better you build that list with a filter:

```
this.numOfunverifiedUsers = this.users.filter(
  user => user.id_verified === 0
);
console.log(this.numOfunverifiedUsers);
console.log(this.numOfunverifiedUsers.length);
```

If you want to read about filter: [Filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

With `this.numOfunverifiedUsers = elem`, you are assigning 'elem' to an array reference. As a result, you get exceptions which make the '=' operator return the undefined primitive type (as the result of function errors; see [undefined - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#Description)). What you want to do is either add the element iteratively into the array the "old way", via element assigning, or just use the OOP way via the push method. The former wouldn't require a count function, as you can do something like that:

```
var count = 0; //outside the forEach 
...
if (elem.id_verified === 0) {
{
      this.numOfunverifiedUsers[count++]=elem
      console.log(count)        
}
...
```

However, as others pointed out, using a filter makes the code much more clean and readable

Answer (score 0):

This would work better with the use of a Filter

```
console.log(this.users.filter(function (val) {
return val.id_verified === 0
}).length)
```

filter items that are id_verified === 0 and count their length.